# Conflicting Event Handlers - How To Control Which Handler Is Triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a list of addresses on my page.  Each time a new address is added, I do an Ajax save and then append the new address to my list of addresses. Each address is in a DIV with a class assigned to it and I have delegated a click handler for that class so that when the address div is clicked, I do something with it.  What I want to do is include a link within in each address div that allows me to edit that particular address.  The problem is that when the link is clicked and the handler is invoked for the link, I'm also triggering the handler for the div.  My question is: how can I handle the "Edit" link click without also triggering the click handler for the div it lives within?

```
<div id="addrdiv">
    <div class="customer-shipping-address">
        Name 1
        Addr 1
        <a href='' class='addredit'>Edit This Address</a>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-shipping-address">
        Name 2
        Addr 2
        <a href='' class='addredit'>Edit This Address</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because addresses are being appended into addrdiv, I have delegated the click handler for each div click and each link click like so:

```
$("#addrdiv").delegate(".customer-shipping-address", "click", function(e){
    // do things here when someone clicks the address block
    ...
}

$("#addrdiv").delegate(".addredit", "click", function(e){
    // do things here when someone clicks the edit link within the block
    ...
}
```

When someone clicks the Edit link within each address, I want the link's handler to fire and not the one for the address block as a whole.  Is this possible to do?  If so, how?

Comment: stopPropagation.


BOOOOOM

Comment: it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() @RubenSerrate

Comment: @StevenWeb   hahaha....        NO


 http://jsfiddle.net/L52xco6w/

Comment: Of course my mistake. Just read the documentation here (http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). And missunderstudt it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I did a fiddle to justify my comment, I though I would post it as an answer.

You need to call the stopPropagation method so the event stops bubbling up through the DOM ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L52xco6w/)):

```
$("#addrdiv").delegate(".customer-shipping-address", "click", function(e){
    // do things here when someone clicks the address block
    ...
}

$("#addrdiv").delegate(".addredit", "click", function(e){
    // do things here when someone clicks the edit link within the block
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

stopPropagation() would be a quick way to achieve this, just call it within the `.addredit` handler on the event

```
$("#addrdiv").delegate(".addredit", "click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('edit clicked');
});
```

here is a fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/phcjdfzd/

Answer (score 0):

In the event object there is a property "target", this property is the clicked element in this case, so you can check if event.target == this.

Example using jQuery .is :

```
$("#addrdiv").delegate(".customer-shipping-address", "click", function(e){
    if($(e.target).is(this)) {
        //you can do $(e.target).is(".customer-shipping-address") too
        console.log("clicked element is .customer-shipping-address");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is useful - it doesn't exactly answer my question, but I can see definite use for this. thanks

Answer (score -2):

you need to attach the event to the link.

```
$("#addrdiv .customer-shipping-address a").delegate(".addredit", "click", function(e){

}
```

Comment: this will not stop the event bubbling up though

Comment: actually not sure ths would work at all as .addredit is not a child of the a

Comment: your right, i was thinking of $("#addrdiv .addredit").click(function () {e.stopPropagation(); });